# Сортировка дерева каталогов

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

У меня есть дерево каталогов, которое я храню в обычном массиве. Элементе этого массива представляет собой что-то типа такого:

```
var obj = { id: 1, parent_id: null, name: "Folder" }
```

Проблема в том, что этот массив не отсортированный, а я хочу его отсортировать так, чтобы порядок примерно вот таким:

```
Folder1
  Sub_folder1
    Sub_sub_folder1
  Sub_folder2
    Sub_sub_folder2
```

То есть порядок должен быть как в обычно дереве каталогов.

Не хотелось бы использовать рекурсию... Думал прилепить искусственное поле, которое бы задавало номер следования элементов, но сразу же понял, что это не решение...

Вот моя попытка:

```
var sort = function(list) {

  var f_map = {};
  var sorting_index = 1;
  var tree = angular.copy(list);

  for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {

    var node = tree[i];
    f_map[ node.id ]= { index: i, children: [] };

    if (node.parent_id) {
      f_map[ node.parent_id ].children.push( node.id );
    };

    var idx = 0;
    var visited = {};

    for(var key in f_map) {
      var index = f_map[key].index;
      var node = tree[index];
      if (!visited[node.id]) {
        node.nuid = idx++;
      } else {
        visited[node.id] = true;
      };
      if (f_map[key].children.length) {
        var children = f_map[key].children;
        for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
          var child_id = children[i];
          var child_idx = f_map[child_id].index;
          var child = tree[child_idx];
          child.nuid = idx++;
          visited[child.id] = true;
        };
      };
    };

    tree.sort(function(left, right) {
      return left.nuid - right.nuid;
    });

    return tree;
};
```

Кто-нибудь знает как бы хорошо решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Помните, что сортируемые элементы обязательно должны удовлетворять одному простому свойству: они должны быть сравнимы. Если вы придумаете такой набор атрибутов для каждого элемента, что эти элементы можно будет сравнить, то вам останется только взять любой алгоритм сортировки и использовать его.

Т.к. в вашем примере явно прослеживается сортировка в алфавитном порядке, то можно ввести поле orderName и использовать конкатенацию имен всех parent-элементов и самого листового элемента. Тогда можно будет сортировать по этому полю (строки сравнимы).

Answer (score 1):

По моему логичнее написать функцию сравнения элементов и воспользоваться стандартной сортировкой массивов. 
Вот набросок на скорую руку:

```
var arr = [{id:10,parent:1,name:"Z"},{id:2,parent:10,name:"Ssf1"},{id:5,parent:1,name:"G"},{id:1,parent:null,name:"F1"},{id:8,parent:5,name:"Ssf2"},{id:4,parent:10,name:"Ssf0"},{id:8,parent:5,name:"Ssf8"}];

arr.sort(function (a,b) {
  if (a.id == b.parent) {
    if (a.parent < b.parent) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.parent > b.parent) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return ( a.name < b.name ) ? -1 : ( a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0 );
    }
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});

JSON.stringify(arr)
```

Если не устроит, то несложно допилить до нужной кондиции, но это уже сами...
Оставлю подсказку - сделать это нужно в else первого if.
Удачи!

PS возможно даже сделаете красивее и короче - воля ваша ;)

PS2 на дорожку, ссылка по тебе (на сам сайт то же обратите внимание) - http://javascript.ru/Array/sort